# Designing/Using a user table in Cassandra with account creation

Tags: database-design, cassandra

I'm new to Cassandra and I'm starting off by designing a simple user table for account registration and login purposes. This is pretty simple:

Row key: username; Columns: email, name, password, salt.
Or alternatively:
Row key: uuid; Columns: username, email, name, password, salt.

Regarding this simple structure, I've got two questions:

1. I need an index for the email (and username) lookup. I can use a secondary index or manually create an index. Should I choose the second option because of the high cardinality of the email/username columns? Apparently secondary indexes are intended for low cardinality columns.
2. More importantly, I immediately run into the problem of concurrently inserting keys into the table - I need to do a read-before-write to make sure that the username(or email) isn't already in the database. Is there a way to avoid the potential race conditions (e.g. two users registering the same username/email at the same time)? Or is the correct solution to use an additional relational database for handling user registration and copy over user account details to the cassandra database for login and other purposes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes you need to create your own index for the reasons you state.  Emails and usernames will be unique and are therefore a bad candidate for a secondary index.
2. In any case requiring a unique value you will have to read before write.  Since the case where two users would select the same username simultaneously is possibly rare (depends on your traffic), you could just cross your fingers and hope it works.  Alternatively you can follow this flow:

   - Do a read to check for existence of the user
   - If it doesn't exist, write the record and hold onto the timestamp you use
   - Read the user again and compare the timestamps
   - If the timestamp is incorrect (implying someone else following the same flow overwrote the first record), prompt the user to supply a different name

The flow in #2 will have the effect that the second user to write the same username within the time window will win, but I presume this is ok as long as you tell at least one user that the name is taken.